# VS Code terminal doesn't run a C++ program when building with Ctrl + Shift + B

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-code, g++, mingw

I'm using Visual Studio Code for C++ coding and I'm using g++.exe for compiling with MinGW for building.
It builds and runs my C++ code properly when I **do not** use Ctrl + Shift + B. (`F1 -> C/C++ : Build and Debug Active file->  g++.exe`)
However, once I use Ctrl + Shift + B, it goes wrong. The terminal says the build has been succeeded, but it does not run the created .exe file and keeps silence saying

`Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.`

When I rebuild it by `F1 -> C/C++ : Build and Debug Active file->  g++.exe` it works.

What is wrong with it?
Here is my `tasks.json` file

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe アクティブなファイルのビルド",
            "command": "C:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "デバッガーによって生成されたタスク。"
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe アクティブなファイルのビルド ver(1)",
            "command": "C:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "デバッガーによって生成されたタスク。"
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe アクティブなファイルのビルド",
            "command": "C:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "デバッガーによって生成されたタスク。"
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe アクティブなファイルのビルド ver(1)",
            "command": "C:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "デバッガーによって生成されたタスク。"
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe アクティブなファイルのビルド ver(2)",
            "command": "C:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "デバッガーによって生成されたタスク。"
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe アクティブなファイルのビルド",
            "command": "C:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "コンパイラ: C:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe アクティブなファイルのビルド",
            "command": "C:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "コンパイラ: C:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe アクティブなファイルのビルド ver(3)",
            "command": "C:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "デバッガーによって生成されたタスク。"
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe アクティブなファイルのビルド ver(4)",
            "command": "C:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "デバッガーによって生成されたタスク。"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: It's not supposed to run the program when you press `Ctrl + Shift + B`, it's only supposed to build it.

Comment: Thank you. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally in Visual Studio (all editions) the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> is for the Build command. It does not run the program.

In Visual Studio, a debug session is started using the <kbd>F5</kbd> shortcut (which automatically builds the program before starting it).

With that said, if you really want it, you can change <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> in *File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts* to "*Build and debug active file*" or "*Debug: Continue*".
You can assign any keyboard shortcut to any available command really.

Comment: Thank you.  According to your advice, I tried push F5 and found some pop up menu like `C++(GDB/LLDB)` and `C++(Windows)`, but I don't know what they are used for. Are they debug tools?  I want to use  `C/C++ IntelliSense, debugging, and code browsing` in which I've already set a Compiler Path.

Comment: You need to setup Launch configuration(s) (`launch.json` as explained [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging)). The F5 button runs the last used Launch configuration. If you don't want to, you can try assigning a key binding to the "*Build and debug active file*" command.